# Apple script not working on Mavericks with Microsoft outlook

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I am trying to execute a simple Apple script on Mavericks but its not executing. The error i am facing is "expected end of line but found class name"

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set currentTime to (the current date)
    set newEvent to make new calendar event with properties{subject:"New Appointment", start time:(currentTime + (60 *60)/2), end time:(currentTime + (60 * 60) +(60)/2)}
    open newEvent
end tell
```

I tried removing the duplicate dictionaries by running the command

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

Rebooting the Mac , Re Installing the outlook and Reinstalling Mavericks as well but still the same problem.

Can some one please suggest me any fresh ideas i'm totally out of  all.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Comment: your script runs fine for me I'm running OSX 10.9.4 and MSO 14.4.3 could you check and see if your versions are the same ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah the versions are same  and its happening only on my system. I have another system with same OS X version and MSO 14.4.3 and this apple script is absolutely working fine there.

Comment: There is some thing different in two systems i am not sure what it is.

Comment: On my work Mac, which was a newly-built Mavericks image with Office installed onto it and then had my data restored to it, I found that pre-existing Applescripts that contained the statement 'tell application "Microsoft Outlook"' failed to compile, presumably failing to link to the correct dictionary. Changing the statement to 'tell application "Outlook"' enabled it to compile. The statement was then rewritten to 'tell application "Microsoft Outlook"'. Then it fails to compile again. Every time I reopen the script, it fails again. I first saw this behavior documented here: http://stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

It almost just looks like your script isn't properly delimited with line endings.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set currentTime to (the current date)
    set newEvent to make new calendar event with properties {subject:"New Appointment", start time:(currentTime + (60 * 60) / 2), end time:(currentTime + (60 * 60) + (60) / 2)}
    open newEvent
end tell
```

It should look like that.

Comment: @mcgrailm The way he had it written earlier, it was just one line of code. The error he was receiving could have just been on his build. It appears that is now not the case anymore. I don't have Outlook on this comp to test it unfortunately :/

Comment: @double_j : I tried executing the same script  which you have provided and  its just results the same Error "Expected end of line, etc. but found class name."

Comment: @kishore I was able to try this on a Comp that I have with the Outlook app. There was no error returned and it worked fine. Is this the only part of your script that you are using, or is there more? Also, are you able to build the Applescript before it runs? Try pressing Command "k" in Applescript before you run the script to make sure it will build the script and is able to run.

Comment: I tried and its not compiling and returning me the error. I tried the same script on couple of other systems and its working there. I am not sure why its not working on my system.

Comment: @Kishore Do you have Outlook installed on that computer?

Comment: Yes I do have outlook 14.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Just a formatting note... it should look like this:

```
set currentTime to (the current date)
set startTime to currentTime + (30 * minutes) -- + 30 minutes
set endTime to currentTime + (1 * hours) + 30 -- + 1 hour 30 seconds

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set newEvent to make new calendar event with properties {subject:"New Appointment", start time:startTime, end time:endTime}
    open newEvent
end tell
```